# jQuery Ajax returning 404 Error, but correct Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm posting some data to a PHP script via jQuery AJAX, and everything executes correctly, but it returns a 404 error.  In my Firebug console the response from the PHP script is correct.  I don't understand how the script can respond, and it is still throwing a 404 error.  The jQuery "error" callback method triggers, and the "success" method doesn't.

All statements performed by the PHP script work accurately, because I can see the database being updated, etc.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, on a WordPress 3.x website hosted by Dreamhost.

**-----------MORE INFO-----------**

OK, I've figured out that when I include WordPress's `wp-blog-header.php` file in the Ajax script, I get the error. Also, once upon a time these scripts work, and I am 90% sure they stopped working after the WP 3.0 update.  I'll paste in the Response headers from Firebug.

**This header response from PHP that includes the wp-blog-header.php and returns a 404 error in Firebug...**

```
Date                Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:44:44 GMT
Server            Apache
X-Powered-By        PHP/5.2.6
X-Pingback        http://www.learnwake.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires          Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control       no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma            no-cache
Last-Modified       Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:44:44 GMT
Vary                Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length    36
Keep-Alive        timeout=2, max=98
Connection        Keep-Alive
Content-Type        text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**This header response from PHP that doesn't include the wp-blog-header.php and returns a 200 OK in Firebug...**

```
Date                Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:44:58 GMT
Server            Apache
X-Powered-By        PHP/5.2.6
Vary                Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length    36
Keep-Alive        timeout=2, max=100
Connection        Keep-Alive
Content-Type        text/html
```

Comment: Pls check the php script if there's a line that send header 404

Comment: You should edit this new discovery into your original question.

Comment: @alex - Just did. Thanks for the input/advice.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you include `wp-blog-header.php`, you end up bootstrapping the whole WordPress setup routine. The function `wp()` is called, which calls `$wp->main()`, which in turn calls various setup functions.

One of these is `$wp->query_posts()`, which calls `$wp_the_query->query()`, which in turn calls `WP_Query`'s `parse_query()` function. I *suspect* that the 404 indication is generated in there (your AJAX page isn't a WP post, or anything like that), and is later transformed into an actual 404 response header by `$wp->handle_404()`, the function called after `query_posts()` in `main()`.

I'm not 100% sure that `parse_query()` is the definite culprit, but I would suggest seeing if you can just include `wp-load.php` instead, since I believe it does the actual work of creating the objects that you want to access.

Again, I don't actually use WordPress, so I can't be sure, but looking at the source code this seems to be the most likely case, from what I can tell.

Comment: Tim.  I love you so much you have no idea.  This has haunted me for some time.  Changing the include to wp-load.php made the difference.  So, at the end of the day, I assume it WAS the WordPress upgrade that caused the issue.

Comment: "i don't actually use wordpress" i do and obviously you know a lot more about it than i do...you are awesome!!

Comment: Tim and Mike, love you both ! :) Just started on debugging the issue when I found your answer. It would certainly have taken some time and am on a deadline

Comment: Your answer is completely correct and worked for me, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've added an `ajax.php` file in a WordPress template once, and had this problem.

I solved it simply by adding at the top of `ajax.php`

```
header('Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```

Kind of a hack, but it worked.

Comment: I placed that both at the top and bottom of the PHP script, but didn't help.

Comment: It should be just after you include `wp-header.php`, IIRC.

Comment: Yup, tried.  Still didn't work.  Finally got it resolved.  Thanks for your time and patience!

Answer (score 3):

No one else posted this as an answer, so it's worth noting. You should be including `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`.

If you open up `wp-blog-header.php` you'll see why:

```
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

If you are only outputting json for an AJAX operation, you do *not* need to include `template-loader.php`. This will create unnecessary overhead, and then of course provide the 404 error.

This 'workaround' is necessary for current and future versions of WordPress. I'm assuming anything past 3.0 should include `wp-load.php` as stated.

Answer (score 1):

Overall there aren't a ton of places where WordPress will return a 404. I recommending grepping the source tree for those places and placing some debug code to trace why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Tim, I changed the hook I was catching from "wp" to "init" in my plugin and it stopped giving me the 404.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The Fix.

Change:

```
require_once('wp-blog-header.php');
```

To:

```
require_once('conn.php');
require('wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();
```

This will also fix HTTP header errors if you want to have a page outside WP.