# jQuery/Ajax Wordpress Pagination 404 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404

I'm making a theme which will allow my wordpress to flip through pages without reloading the page using jQuery.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it has to be something with the way I call the new page within wordpress which is giving my JavaScript Console a 404 error, even though if I click on the link the console provides to the not found page, it loads fine

I'm sharing with you the JavaScript code I used, and the page it loads within the div as I'm pretty positive that page is where the problem is.  If I try to create a test PHP file with some passed variables it loads fine.

My JavaScript:

```
function nextpage(page) {

page++;

$('#ajaxloading').text('Loading...');   

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: homeUrl+"/wp-ajax-post.php?p="+page+"",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#ajaxcontent').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

My wp-ajax-post.php:

```
<?php
require('wp-blog-header.php');
$wp_query = new WP_Query('paged=' . $_GET['p']); 
?>
<div id="content" style="width:400px;margin:auto;background:#c30000;padding:20px;">

        <?php /* Top post navigation */ ?>

        <?php /* The Loop — with comments! */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

        <?php /* Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() */ ?>
                        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php /* an h2 title */ ?>
                            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'hbd-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <?php /* Microformatted, translatable post meta */ ?>
                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'hbd-theme'); ?></span>
                                <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_link( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'hbd-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
                                <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
                                <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-entry-date"><?php _e('Published ', 'hbd-theme'); ?></span>
                                <span class="entry-date"><abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></abbr></span>
                                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'hbd-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t" ) ?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

        <?php /* The entry content */ ?>
                            <div style="height:50%;overflow-y:auto;" class="entry-content"  id="#ajaxloading">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'hbd-theme' )  ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'hbd-theme' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <?php /* Microformatted category and tag links along with a comments link */ ?>
                            <div class="entry-utility">
                                <span class="cat-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links"><?php _e( 'Posted in ', 'hbd-theme' ); ?></span><?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></span>
                                <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
                                <?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'hbd-theme' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n" ) ?>
                                <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'hbd-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'hbd-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'hbd-theme' ) ) ?></span>
                                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'hbd-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n" ) ?>
                            </div><!-- #entry-utility -->
                        </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

        <?php /* Close up the post div and then end the loop with endwhile */ ?>      
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php pagenavi(); ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
```

Comment: you are getting page number here $wp_query = new WP_Query('paged=' . $_GET['p']); from request but it is not being used any where

Comment: @AmitChotaliya , It's loading the page query. When i go to the wp-ajax-post.php and and pass in those variables myself it goes to the proper pages...

Comment: I looked into the proper way of using WP_Query and have modified this line `<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post() ?>`  but I still get the same results

Answer (score 0):

So, although I'm apparently not doing this the most "correct" way when it comes to WordPress, I have figured out the problem thanks to another post here on StackOverflow.

[jQuery Ajax returning 404 Error, but correct Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445270/jquery-ajax-returning-404-error-but-correct-response)

The problem is with:

```
require('wp-blog-header.php');
```

It should be:

```
include('wp-load.php');
```

Although that did create a few issues with some global variables in my plugin I was able to get around it... I know this isn't the "correct" way to accomplish ajax in Wordpress since it's built in, but It worked for me.