# 404 error when binding named function with jQuery ajax inside

Tags: jquery, ajax, function-binding

Doing an ajax request when click button works fine, return as expected. But the problem is when I try to bind a function to an element with an ajax request inside.

The function give me 404 error on this url, but the file exist (same server, same domain...)

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.searcher-rooms .button').click(function() {
        var n = jQuery.now(),
            l = jQuery('.town-list').val(),
            c = jQuery('.short-hotel-list').val();
        if (l == null) {
            l = 'all';
        };
        if (c == null) {
            c = 'all-hotels';
        };
        if (l != '' && l != 'all' && l != 'current') {
            n += '&l='+l;
        };
        if (c != '' && c != 'all-hotels') {
            n += '&c='+c;
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: theme.child_theme_uri+'/searcher.php?t='+n,
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery('#data-wrapper').addClass('loading');
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            jQuery('#data-wrapper').html(data).attr('data-time', n.toString().split('&')[0]).attr('data-location', l).attr('data-hotel', c);
            jQuery('#data-wrapper').removeClass('loading');
            jQuery('.load-more-hotels').bind('click', d_more_hotels);
        })
    })
});

function d_more_hotels() {
    var e = jQuery('#data-wrapper'),
        t = e.attr('data-time'),
        l = e.attr('data-location'),
        c = e.attr('data-hotel'),
        w = jQuery('.load-more-hotels').attr('data-page');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: theme.child_theme_uri+'/searcher.php?t='+t+'&l='+l+'&c='+c+'&w='+w,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function() {
            jQuery('#data-wrapper').addClass('loading');
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        jQuery('#data-wrapper').html(data)
        jQuery('#data-wrapper').removeClass('loading');
        jQuery('.load-more-hotels').attr('data-page', parseInt(w)+1).unbind().bind('click', d_more_hotels);
    })
}
```

jQuery.ajax function inside "d_more_hotels" function give a 404 error in url, but the file exists.

I've checked all variables and doing a log to see full url param used, but all seems ok.

Working under WordPress last version framework.

:S

Any help is apreciated.

EDIT:

Solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445620/3676282

WordPress function mess

Comment: Hi, to solve this kind of errors, the developer tools that usually come with your browser are very helpful. In Chrome, for example, right-click anywhere on the page and choose "inspect element". In the view that appears, click the "Network" tab. After that, try calling the functions, and check if there are any differences between the requests.

Comment: why your t, l, c and w are not declared as a var? and I think these variables value contains quote's , can you verify these values?

Comment: @user1582024 XHR type both, all are identical but the working one is "Content-Encoding:gzip". Accesing directly the url that gives the error return data as expected.

Comment: @NitinDhomse you can declare many variables in one statement. Don't need prepend "var" to every variable.

Comment: ohh, these are comma separated, I was confused due to separate line.

Comment: Generated url seems like this: http://domain.com/project/wp-content/themes/main-theme/searcher.php?t=1468846232819&l=all&c=all-hotels&w=2 accesing file directly works and return data, but 404 error if accesing through ajax request in binded function

Comment: Solution -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/3445620/3676282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445620/3676282

404 error fired due to Wordpress security

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
  url: theme.child_theme_uri+'/searcher.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {"t":t, "l":l, "c":c, "w":w} ,
```

Comment: Not working. If I send get variables like this, first ajax call (defined when jQuery('.searcher-rooms .button') is clicked) return 404 error (the same, 404 error, but url well built and working as standalone).